# Approximate to the nearest degree, the two solutions of the equation $\cos^2x - 3\cos x -1=0$ in the interval [$0$ degrees, $360$ degrees].

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

> Approximate to the nearest degree, the two solutions of the equation $\cos^2x - 3\cos x -1=0$ in the interval [$0$ degrees, $360$ degrees].

How do I solve the question above? I tried factoring but that doesn't work since none of them have a common factor.

Answer (score 1):

You could complete the square or apply a $\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$-type formula to find solutions for $\cos(x)$, and then solve for $x$.

You need to watch out for multiple solutions both for the quadratic and the arccosine.